# What is the difference between “nachvollziehen” and “verstehen”?

Tags: difference, verb, verb-usage

What is the difference between *nachvollziehen* and *verstehen*? In my dictionary they both mean “to comprehend”. Do they have a big difference in usage?

Comment: well nachvollziehen has usually a more distanced connotation. You can retrace the way someone has arrived to the thought, but (in some contextes) you might not agree. Like: "ich kann nachvolliehen warum du so denkst, aber ich bin nicht einverstanden", meaning "i can see where you're coming from, but i disagree".
It can also be used in the context of a more complicated concept, when you understand each single step that leads to the final conclusion, and not just the conclusion per se.

Verstehen, on the other hand, has a more positive connotation. "ich habe verstanden", "i grasped the concept".

Answer (score 10):

Short summary:

If you are either able *to retrace* or *to reconstruct* something or able *to follow* someone, then you can use *[nachvollziehen](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nachvollziehen)*. If, however, it's just about understanding and comprehension of the nature of something, you can only use *[verstehen](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/verstehen)*.

---

Elaborated answer:

Both words have an overlapping sense but *verstehen* is a little broader in meaning. You can use *verstehen* when you are able to hear someone, as in *Can you hear me?*:

> Kannst du mich verstehen?

Or if you didn't understand someone, then you say:

> Ich kann dich (akustisch) nicht verstehen.

Apart from that, *verstehen* is basically used in the sense of *to understand* the meaning or significance of something. Examples:

> - Die Bedienungsanleitung versteht kein Mensch.
> - Unterschreiben Sie nichts, was Sie nicht verstehen.
> - Ich kann nicht verstehen, wie man so viel Glück auf einmal haben kann.
> - Ich verstehe nicht, warum es dir so wichtig ist.
> - Ich verstehe sehr gut, dass ...

As you probably noticed, *verstehen* is literally quite close *to understand*. See also notes on [Etymology Online](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=understand) and Wiktionary entry for *[forstand](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/forstand)*.

*Nachvollziehen* is synonymous to *verstehen* in many contexts. I think there's a simple way to find out if that is true. This is actually already mentioned in the other answer, I will just put it in another way again.

The meaning of *nachvollziehen* is *to retrace* or *to reconstruct* something in mind. Example: If you are able to retrace the feelings someone has when someone close to them died, you can say<sup>1</sup>:

> Ich kann sehr gut nachvollziehen, was du durchmachst.

Another example: Your math teacher explains how to solve an equation and you are not able *to follow* him, i.e. how to get from, e.g., step 3 to step 4, you can say:

> Ich kann nicht ganz nachvollziehen, wie man von Schritt 3 zu Schritt 4 kommt.

In both example you can still go with *verstehen* though.

---

<sup>1</sup>: I am aware that you hardly ever will be able to fully understand what someone is feeling in such a moment; it's just an example to make my point.

Comment: Ich kann die Antwort nicht nachvollziehen. Die 5 Punkte oben (Bedienungsanleitung, ...) kann man auch alle mit "kann nachvollziehen" bilden.

Comment: Was ist falsch an "Die Bedienungsanleitung kann kein Mensch nachvollziehen"? An "Unterschreiben Sie nichts, was Sie nicht nachvollziehen können". "Ich kann nicht nachvollziehen, wie man so viel Glück auf einmal haben kann." "Ich kann nicht nachvollziehen, warum es dir so wichtig ist." "Ich kann sehr gut nachvollziehen, dass ...".

Answer (score 4):

"Nachvollziehen" and "verstehen" both are very similar in meaning (as you already found out), but there are some subtle differences that I want to emphasize here.

**Example A:**
At first you don't understand the reasoning behind someones decision and they explain it to you. You then do understand the chain of thoughts that let to that decision.
Here, you'd rather use "nachvollziehen".
"Verstehen" is valid here as well, but doesn't carry the deductive meaning.

> Das kann ich nachvollziehen".
>   Das ist nachvollziehbar.

**Example B:**
If you're unable to understand something for technical reasons, like acoustic failure or irritating noises, it would be wrong to use "nachvollziehen".

> Wie bitte? Das habe ich nicht verstanden.

**Negating:**
Since the word "nachvollziehen" refers basically to the brain-action of understanding something instead of the ear-action (yes, my English is awesome today), you usually don't negate it in the standard way:
Use

> Das kann ich nicht nachvollziehen.

instead of

> *Das habe ich nicht nachvollzogen.

These details are kinda specific, so you should be fine with using both words synonymously in (most?) other places. When in doubt, use "verstehen" since it's more common.

Comment: Ex. A ist falsch. Eine Argumentationskette wird sowohl nachvollzogen als auch verstanden. Einen mathematischen Beweis zu verstehen und nachzuvollziehen ist das gleiche. Kannst Du das nachvollziehen? Verstehst Du das Argument?

Answer (score 2):

There is also one practical detail about the difference between the two.

When there is a discussion going on and somebody replies to what another person says starting with "Das (what you say) kann ich nachvollziehen" instead of "Das kann ich verstehen" it can be a very diplomatic way to introduce a contrary opinion. Because "Das kann ich nachvollziehen" implies that although you don't really agree with him you perfectly understood why he thinks that way which lends your following contrary statement more substance. If you would have said "Ich kann das verstehen" it somehow implies to a little extent that you AGREE with his view, you agree to his thoughts in that context he explains while nachvollziehen is more UNDERSTAND his thoughts.

But the difference is still very tiny..

Answer (score 1):

In English, if someone tries to explain something and you don't get it, you might say, "I don't follow." This would be a situation to use 'nachvollziehen'.

Answer (score 0):

Nachvollziehen has the connotations of *coming* to understand, or in American English slang "getting" something after a step-by-step process.

Verstehen refers to "understanding" in the sense of fully comprehending something, or grasping the whole, with one "shot".

Comment: Ich kann die Relativitätstheorie nachvollziehen und verstehen - beides ist gleich geeignet die Gänze der Theorie zu meinen. Ebenso kann ich den Wunsch zwischen den Begriffen einen Unterschied sehen zu wollen verstehen und nachvollziehen, auch wenn er zu keiner belastbaren Aussage führt, außer dass das akustische Verstehen nicht durch Nachvollziehen ersetzt werden kann.

Comment: @userunknown: Is this better (after my changes)?

Comment: M.E. nicht. Verstehen hat auch die Konnotation von einer Argumentation, einer Ursachen-Wirkungskette folgen zu können. Ebenso wird nachvollziehen auch verwendet für das Ad-Hoc-Erfassen eines ganzen Zusammenhangs oder Gefühls. M.E. wird hier versucht die Wörter überspezifisch zu betrachten; ihnen eine Trennschärfe zuzuweisen, die sie im Alltag der Sprache schlicht nicht haben. Es geht ja nicht darum, was Du oder ich lieber wann benutzt, sondern was richtiger Sprachgebrauch ist.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about acoustics, you'd always use `verstehen` instead of `nachvollziehen`. So the latter is always about comprehension, usually about understanding every step of a procedure. The former can be used for both, but in a slightly more generic sense.

Answer (score -1):

**Nachvollziehen** means to comprehend a **complex** situation by retracing it step by step from beginning to end until you **get** how this situation or outcome appeared.

**Verstehen** means just that you **got it**. Usually without having to retrace the steps. Because the thing to understand was less complex or in other words **simple enough to get / understand** without having to get a long explanation.

Or you had similar experience and "knew" the steps already. But then if it is **complex**, you can "**nachvollziehen**"; if it is **simple**, you just "**verstehen**".

Comment: Alle Aussagen sind falsch. Einen komplizierten, mathematischen Beweis über 5 Seiten kann man sehr wohl verstehen und das bedeutet nichts anderes, als ihn nachvollziehen zu können - ob es anstrengend war oder nicht ist dabei nicht von Belang. Ebenso benutzt man Nachvollziehen wenn man emotionale Zustände oder intuitiv Erfasstes, Gefühle teilen kann, ohne sich intellektuell die Situation klar zu machen.

Answer (score -1):

Although far less technical than the other answers, I think of the English slang phrase "I'm picking up what you're putting down."  If that phrase works better than "I understand", then you nachvollziehen is more appropriate.  Again, not nearly as scientific as the explanations above, but it seems to work fairly well.